# Append a dict to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, parsing

I'm trying to parse five tax identification numbers so that for each of them I can display inclusion labels and the number of records, but I get the following error. I tried a lot of what was suggested on the Internet, nothing helped, who knows?

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;Win64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[
        "Значение",
        "Найдено результатов",
        "ИНН поставщика",
        "Даты включения",
        "Количество записей",
    ]
)

values = [9704093992, 9718162290, 7727362380, 9723114824, 9701225810]

for value in values:
    url = f"https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/dishonestsupplier/search/results.html?searchString={value}&morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&savedSearchSettingsIdHidden=&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false&fz94=on&fz223=on&ppRf615=on&dsStatuses=&inclusionDateFrom=&inclusionDateTo=&lastUpdateDateFrom=&lastUpdateDateTo="
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all("div", class_="search-registry-entry-block")
    for result in results:
        data = result.find("div", class_="registry-entry__body-block").text.strip()
        inclusion_date = result.find("div", class_="data-block__value").text.strip()
        record_count = result.find("div", class_="search-results__total")
        df = df.append(
            {
                "Значение": value,
                "Найдено результатов": len(results),
                "ИНН поставщика": data,
                "Даты включения": inclusion_date,
                "Количество записей": record_count,
            },
            ignore_index=True,
        )


df.to_excel("results.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Dataframes don't have `.append()`. I'd recommend just appending to a list-of-dicts and turning that list into a dataframe afterwards.

Comment: Do you any other ways?

Comment: What is wrong with that way? It's shorter and easier.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, DataFrames don't accept values through append () function because, this function is applicable to only lists or tuples.

So, I would suggest the following way of inputting values:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;Win64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[
        "Значение",
        "Найдено результатов",
        "ИНН поставщика",
        "Даты включения",
        "Количество записей",
    ]
)

values = [9704093992, 9718162290, 7727362380, 9723114824, 9701225810]

for value in values:
    url = f"https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/dishonestsupplier/search/results.html?searchString={value}&morphology=on&search-filter=%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&savedSearchSettingsIdHidden=&sortBy=UPDATE_DATE&pageNumber=1&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_10&showLotsInfoHidden=false&fz94=on&fz223=on&ppRf615=on&dsStatuses=&inclusionDateFrom=&inclusionDateTo=&lastUpdateDateFrom=&lastUpdateDateTo="
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all("div", class_="search-registry-entry-block")
    for result in results:
        data = result.find("div", class_="registry-entry__body-block").text.strip()
        inclusion_date = result.find("div", class_="data-block__value").text.strip()
        record_count = result.find("div", class_="search-results__total")
        df["Значение"] = value
        df["Найдено результатов"] = len(results)
        df["ИНН поставщика"] = data
        df["Даты включения"] = inclusion_rate
        df["Количество записей"] = record_count


df.to_excel("results.xlsx", index=False)
```

To the best of my knowledge, this should work.